# Install a Git branch as npm dependency and a Git branch as npm DEV dependency

Tags: git, npm

I've searched everywhere but I can't find a solution.

**My issue :** I want to install a npm package from a branch as dependency and use another branch as dev dependency

Because I've got the same package name, it installs the package as devDependency OR dependency

I can't do this command line : `npm i git+ssh://git@<gitlab_url>.git#testing && npm i git+ssh://git@<gitlab_url>.git#dev --save-dev`

**What I expect :**

`"my-library": "git+ssh://git@<gitlab_url>.git#testing"` as dependency

`"my-library": "git+ssh://git@<gitlab_url>.git#dev"` as dev dependency

so that in local I use the `dev` branch and in testing URL I use `testing` branch with continuous deployment.

Is this possible ?
Thanks in advance. If I don't put enough information, comment the post, I'll add some.